# How to *not* expand "~" in tcsh backtick/eval wrapper?

Tags: eval, alias, wrapper, tcsh

*I'm not interested in a "why tcsh is evil" response, this question requires tcsh for it's use.  If this is a bug in tcsh, please just let me know that.*

I'm generally pretty good at quoting output but I've been stumped by a use case I have to deal with.  Here's the simplified case:

I have an executable that I eval the output of.  Sometimes it needs to print output (to stdout) so I have tried using echo (builtin), /bin/echo and /bin/printf.

As a simple example, say my executable is called "simpleWrap" and it **outputs**:

```
echo "hello world"
```

So I run (eventually using an alias, but that's irrelevant here):

```
eval `simpleWrap`
```

And I get, as expected:

```
hello world
```

But here's the problem.  Sometimes I need a tilde in the output.  So let's try some examples.  We'll put tildes in the simpleWrap output (this is not the contents of the script, but what it *outputs*):

```
echo "These are tildes:  ~ and \~ and \\~"
```

And surprisingly when I eval the output of simpleWrap now, I get:

```
These are tildes: /home/dave and \~ and \~
```

Either the ~ is expanded to my home directory, or the \ protects it, but I can't get rid of the backslash.

How can I just print a '~' in the output of an eval with backticks?

I believe the backticks are forcing the ~ expansion, but they aren't doing it in a consistent way.  For example, if I skip the backticks and just do:

```
eval echo "These are tildes:  ~ and \~ and \\~"
```

Then I get a consistent, expected output:

```
These are tildes: /home/dave and ~ and \~
```

Is there something wrong with substitution in backticks, or am I missing the proper quoting possibility?  (I've also tried wrapping in single and double quotes to no avail)

Comment: I don't understand your example or what you're trying to do. `eval \`simpleWrap\`` doesn't produce "Hello world"; the backticks produce "Hello world", and `eval` tries to run the command `Hello world`. that being said, in general my preferred way to fix this is by using `set noglob` (and then re-enabling it with `set glob` later).

Comment: Please read the explanation again - simpleWrap *outputs*  'echo "hello world"', it doesn't just echo hello world.

Comment: To avoid confusions like this is why a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always recommended ;-)

Comment: While I'm not experienced in the language, just throwing in my two cents. Perhaps try to output a unicode `U+007E`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences arises from the *order shell substitutions take place*, and the different behavior of parsing the `\`, when it is inside double-quotes, as opposed to no double-quotes.

To demonstrate the behavior of `\`:

```
echo \~
=> ~
echo "\~"
=> \~
echo "\\~"
=> \~
```

### Scenario 1

```
eval `simpleWrap`
```

Here, "`simpleWrap`" outputs a "raw" string which includes tildes. The string is then passed unchanged (no substitutions) to the eval command (because that's how backticks work), which basically runs a new shell. So the new shell sees this command line:

```
echo "These are tildes:  ~ and \~ and \\~"
```

(Note that the quotes are seen by the `eval` command).

The output of this command is the one you didn't expect, i.e. both `\~` (denote A) and `\\~` (denote B) produce the same output. Why?

First of all, neither A nor B is substituted, because tilde substitution only happens if the tilde is the first character in its word, which isn't the case for either.

Now, for A, since `\~` is not a known escape sequence (unlike `\n` for example), the shell leaves it as is, producing `\~`.

For B, `\\` *is* a known escape sequence, so the shell correctly interprets it as `\`, then appends the rest of the string to it, producing `\~` again.

### Scenario 2

```
eval echo "These are tildes:  ~ and \~ and \\~"
```

Here, there's *only one command line*, which includes the tildes. First, there's the shell substitution, which affects neither A nor B, but in this stage, the quotes drop (they are used for grouping words into a single argument, and are not passed to the command). Then, `eval` runs (`echo` hasn't run yet), and is pass this as input: `echo These are tildes:  ~ and \~ and \\~`.

Note the quotes dropped. The output of the command without the quotes is what you expect (see "demonstration" above):

```
echo These are tildes:  /home/dave and \~ and \\~
=> These are tildes: /home/dave and ~ and \~
```

### How to make it work?

Drop the quotes!

`simpleWrap` should print this:

```
echo These are tildes:  ~ and \~ and \\~
```

instead of this:

```
echo "These are tildes:  ~ and \~ and \\~"
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for a thorough explanation - it didn't occur to me to have less quoting in order to solve the problem.  :)